# unable to do validate data in inputs & create object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i have a issue in getting the all the field values after validation

**requirements:**

will have 3 input fields and in each field we have to enter some value with in a range say like between 2-20 or 50-100 if we enter below or above that it has to display error and if all fields are filled with values then i need to call a api send these data .

**what i did :**

i created input fields along with some validations but here the issue is immediately after validation i am getting that object suppose i have 3 fields if 2 fields are having value and 1 fields is not having then also it is creating object and sending it . I tried putting return false & true in each if statement but it is breaking code.

**issue**
**if am entering the 2 fields and pressing submit also it is creating a object and so here i need to validate all fields and if all fields have satisfy the validation then only it needs to create object or call another function.**

below is my code

```
 <label for='one'>one</label><br />
                      <input type='number' name='one' value=58  pattern="[0-9]" id="one" />%
                      <span id="one_msg"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for='two'>two</label><br />
                      <input type='number' name='two' value='100'  pattern="[0-9]" id="two" />
                      <span id="two_msg"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for='three'>three</label><br />
                      <input type='number' name='three' value=50 pattern="[0-9]" id="three"/>
                      <span id="three_msg"></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type='submit' name='submit' value="submit" onclick="getvalue()" />
```

js code

```
 function getvalue(){
        let text,textOne,textTwo;
        let one = $("#one").val();
        let two = $("#two").val();
        let three = $("#three").val();
        let objData ={};

        if (isNaN(one) || one < 50 || one > 60) {
            text = "Value must be between 50 and 60";
            $("#one_msg").html(text);

          } else {
            text = "";
            objData['one'] = one;
            $("#one_msg").html(text);         
          }
          if (isNaN(two) || two < 1 || two > 100) {
            textOne = "Value must be between 1 and 100";
            $('#two_msg').html(textOne);

          } else {
              textOne = "";
              objData['two'] = two;
             $('#two_msg').html(textOne);
          }
          if (isNaN(three) || three < 30 || three > 60) {
            textTwo = "Value must be between 30 and 60";
            $("#three_msg").html(textTwo);

          } else {
            textTwo = "";
            objData['three'] = three;
            $("#three_msg").html(textTwo);
          }

           console.log(objData)

          // if the object contains all the three object values correctly after validation then only it has to call api

    }
```

NOTE: suppose if have 3 fields and in that 2 fields are having correct values and 1 fields having wrong values then also it is creating object with 2 fields so my requirement is if all the 3 fields are having validated values then only it need to create a object and perform another operation –

Comment: jQuery val return `string`, so you need to convert one, two and three to number, you can use eg. parseInt(one), then you can see if that is lesser then 50 or larger then 1.

Comment: mocni_T here the issue is differnent

Comment: what are the validation conditions for each field ?

Comment: @ths  please check the java script code in the if condition's for each field in getValues()

Comment: you have an `undefined` variable `duration`, what does that variable do ?

Comment: @ths typo error updated it

Comment: You are using value=50, so default value of input is 50 even if user doesn't change it

Comment: Why not just use min and max attributes and put it in a form tag?

Comment: @Lety yes if user changes well and good other wise default values

Comment: @SeanT for each input field we have different values

Comment: So the condition: if (isNaN(three) || three < 30 || three > 60)  is always false. It seems that your code has no bug respect what you want, but it could be possible that I did not understand you :)

Comment: @Lety suppose if have 3 fields and in that 2 fields are having correct values and 1 fields having wrong values then also it is creating object with 2 fields so my requirement is if all the 3 fields are having  validated values then only it need to create a object and perform another operation

Comment: exside answer is a good answer, and you could elaborate creating a checkInput function that perform input value control and based on returned value create object with input value... ths'answer do this :)

Comment: @Dexter you put the min and max attributes on each input field. This is standard browser behaviour that's built in, no need for js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're already using jQuery anyways, you could clean up your code a bit and do as follows:

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 
 const one = $('#one').val();
 const two = $('#two').val();
 const three = $('#three').val();
 let valid = true;
 let objData ={};
 
 if (isNaN(one) || one < 50 || one > 60) {
  $('#one_msg').html('Value must be between 50 and 60');
  valid = false;
 } else {
  $('#one_msg').html('');
 }
 if (isNaN(two) || two < 1 || two > 100) {
  $('#two_msg').html('Value must be between 1 and 100');
  valid = false;
 } else {
  $('#two_msg').html('');
 }
 if (isNaN(three) || three < 30 || three > 60) {
  $('#three_msg').html('Value must be between 30 and 60');
  valid = false;
 } else {
  $('#three_msg').html('');
 }
 
 console.log(objData);
 
 // if the object contains all the three object values correctly after validation then only it has to call api
 if (valid) {
  console.log('Form valid, create object and do API call...');
  objData = {
   one: one,
   two: two,
   three: three,
  };
  
  console.log(objData);
  
  // do your API call...
 }
});
```

```html
<form action="" method="get">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="one">one</label><br />
  <input type="number" name="one" value=58  pattern="[0-9]" id="one" />%
  <span id="one_msg"></span>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="two">two</label><br />
  <input type="number" name="two" value="100"  pattern="[0-9]" id="two" />
  <span id="two_msg"></span>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="three">three</label><br />
  <input type="number" name="three" value=50 pattern="[0-9]" id="three"/>
  <span id="three_msg"></span>
 </div>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: if u see your code if i enter 2 fields and if i left the third field empty of course validation works but stil it is creating object with only 2 fields here if all 3 fields are validated then only it has to create object

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable that acts as a flag : if all the fields are correct populate the `object` otherwise don't do anything.

```js
function getvalue() {
  const one = +$("#one").val(),
    two = +$("#two").val(),
    three = +$("#three").val(),
    oneMsg = $("#one_msg"),
    twoMsg = $("#two_msg"),
    threeMsg = $("#three_msg"),
    objData = {};
  let flag = true;

  if (one < 50 || one > 60) {
    oneMsg.html('Value must be between 50 and 60');
    flag = false;
  } else {
    oneMsg.html('');
  }
  if (two < 1 || two > 100) {
    twoMsg.html('Value must be between 1 and 100');
    flag = false;
  } else {
    twoMsg.html('');
  }
  if (three < 30 || three > 60) {
    threeMsg.html('Value must be between 30 and 60');
    flag = false;
  } else {
    threeMsg.html('');
  }
  
  /** flag is true then populate **/
  if (flag) {
    objData["one"] = one;
    objData["two"] = two;
    objData["three"] = three;
  }

  console.log(objData);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for='one'>one</label><br />
<input type='number' name='one' value=58 pattern="[0-9]" id="one" />%
<span id="one_msg"></span>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for='two'>two</label><br />
  <input type='number' name='two' value='100' pattern="[0-9]" id="two" />
  <span id="two_msg"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for='three'>three</label><br />
  <input type='number' name='three' value=50 pattern="[0-9]" id="three" />
  <span id="three_msg"></span>
</div>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value="submit" onclick="getvalue()" />
```

Comment: but if skip entering one field also and click on submit still it is creating an empty object right ?

Comment: @Dexter the object is declared and initialized already that's way you have an empty one.

Answer (score 1):

Why has nobody suggested just using max and min to handle the validation? Some terrible advice to this question.

```html
<form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="input1">Between 1 and 10 - whole numbers only</label>
  <input name="input1" type="number" min="0" max="10" step="1" />
  <br/>
  <label for="input2">Between 5 and 8 - numbers to hald digit only</label>
  <input name="input2" type="number" min="5" max="8" step="0.5" />
  <br/>
  <label for="input3">Between -5 and 3 - two decimal places</label>
  <input name="input3" type="number" min="-5" max="3" step="0.01" />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Then you can just call:

```
$('form[name="myForm"]').on('submit', function(){
    //Build your object
});
```